# How to prevent mold from building on food and how to kill it along with neurotoxins?

Tags: food, mycology, toxicology, sterilisation

I have some food/fruits chopped in very small parts, whatever it is that needs to be conserved during long time, when it is given to me it can be somewhat wet or humid, after some time of keeping it in a plastic Sterilite it builds mold.

After reading a bit I've learned that an autoclave can kill mold at 100°C at 10psi (68.9kPa) for an hour, but it won't kill toxins. My All American pressure cooker with gauge says it can reach 120°C at 15psi (103.4kPa), however this is not much of a difference.

Vinegar, bleach and borax can all be used, but food becomes unusable.

So here are the two questions:

1. How can I safely keep that food without building mold?
2. If mold does appear, how do I exterminate it along with toxins safely for human health?

Comment: No way to distinguish toxins from nutrients. If it's molded, better throw it away.

Comment: I think this is possibly better asked at Cooking.SE - you are basically asking for something like [canning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canning) , though there are [other approaches too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_preservation) - it mostly depends on the type of food you wish to preserve and how it handles each approach. Vinegar, for example, works well for some foods: though it's not as simple as just soaking your food in vinegar, we typically call it "pickling."

Comment: @BryanKrause Then take the approach at industrial level, suppose the food is blended rice, could something be done? Disposal is not an option.